# on hover "animate" image

Tags: javascript, html, css

my scenario: I have basic image 100x50px. I have one hover jpeg image 300x150 px and it has 9 areas (3x3, each area is 100x50 px and has another image inside). Until there is no on hover event, just another image is shown. Now I am trying to do that on hover these 9 areas changes one by one after 0.3second in cyclic way. Once mouse is not on hover, first image appears back.

```
<div class="thumb">
<a href="click.php"><img src="image.jpg">
<img class="hovered" src="hover.jpg" style="margin-top: 0%; margin-left: 0%; display: none;">
</a>
</div>

<div class="thumb">
<a href="click.php"><img src="another.jpg">
<img class="hovered" src="hovX.jpg" style="margin-top: 0%; margin-left: 0%; display: none;">
</a>
</div>
```

how could I do this please?

(I think I should somehow call javascipt function to display hovered class and start changing position of image each 0.3s. But no idea how..)

MY IMAGES:

first image without hover: [image]

3x3 hover source image: [image]

on hover images cycle like this:
[image]
then after 0.3s [image]
then after another 0.3s  [image]
etc
(numbers are just for reference)

final effect should look like when mouse on hover:
[image]

when mouse is not on hover then this image is shown [image]

Comment: I think is well if you create a work snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using css.
First, put the images into a container element.

```
<div id="img-container">
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
  <div class="hover-img"/>
</div>
```

Now you can set the size and background image of each element in css:

```
#img-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
}
.hover-img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background-image 0.3s;
}
```

I added a transition of 0.3 seconds to the background image so the image will change gradually when we hover over the container. To apply the change on mouse hover, we can set a different image for the hover state of the container. This means that every image will transition to the new image when the container div is hovered over.

```
#img-container:hover>.hover-img {
    background-image: url('hover.jpg');
}
```

Now you want each image to change one-by-one. To do this, you can add a transition delay. You can use css nth-child to target each image directly, though this is a bit long winded and might be better done programmatically with javascript.

```
.hover-img:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 1.8s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(8) {
    transition-delay: 2.1s;
}
.hover-img:nth-child(9) {
    transition-delay: 2.4s;
}
```

I'm not sure if this exactly what you want but I hope it gives some idea of how you could achieve what you want using pure css.

Comment: Welcome to stakoverflow. This is a complete and helpful answer but stackoverflow is not a freelancing programming community. We are here to detect and repair the mistakes in existing codes. Please read the help center to find more https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant (but with images)? You can use onmousover and onmouseout attributes to trigger your animation.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
//instead of colors you'd use source urls
const colors = ["blue","red","green","orange","pink","gold","purple","brown","yellow"];

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  //instead of color you'd add src attribute
  div.style.backgroundColor = colors.shift();
  div.classList.add("square");
  if(i === 0) div.classList.add("active");
  container.append(div);
}

let interval;

function animation() {
  let i = 2;
  container.children[0].classList.toggle("active")
  container.children[1].classList.toggle("active");
  interval = setInterval(()=>{
      if(container.children[i]) {
        container.children[i - 1].classList.toggle("active")
        container.children[i].classList.toggle("active");
      i++
    } else {
      container.children[0].classList.toggle("active")
      container.children[i - 1].classList.toggle("active")
      i = 1; 
    }   
  },300)
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  for(let i = 0; i < container.children.length; i ++){
    const child = container.children[i]; 
    if(child.classList.contains("active")) child.classList.toggle("active");
    if(i === 0)child.classList.toggle("active");
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: 0; 
  pointer-events: none;
}


.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" onmouseover="animation()" onmouseout="reset(this)"></div>
```

Comment: this is very similar to what I need. I added explanation about my scenario in original text

Comment: thanks, it is very close. just it should show from image 3x3, but always just portion of 150x50px is visible. So just this 150x50px area is changing, So I think it will need to change x,y position of 3x3 image in visible area.

Comment: @peter gave it one last shot

Comment: I made one animation how it should peform. I mean, animation should be performed from that one big "hover source image". So it will be not dependant on colors, but when I use another big hover source image in second div, it should work the same with that image.